# VS2010 c++: Change CLSID of COM dll

Tags: c++, dll, com

I need to change the CLSID for my COM DLL.

I tried to simply change the CLSID in the .rgs file.
Is this the valid way, or do I have to do something else?

I am asking because it does not work.

When I change the CLSID in the rgs file, and compile it and then try to use it, I get the "the requested class could not be delivered" error.

Comment: Please make your comment the reply. You were right. I overlooked ONE reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change everything:

- All references to the CLSID in the DLL that implements the COM server.
- The registration code.
- The code that instantiates and consumes the COM server.

I suspect that you didn't manage to get every last reference.